# Gimp Portable and file-jpeg

Tags: gimp, jpeg, portable-apps, error-logging

I have just installed *GIMPPortable* `2.8.22` (32-bit) on a Windows 7 Pro (64-bit) machine.

I cannot open or save JPEG files.  It seems there is something wrong GIMP trying to load the `file-jpeg.exe` file, but I see no specific errors.  All I get is **unknown file type** when trying to open a jpeg directly.  And if attempting to export an xcf image, JPEG is not listed as an option.  I can use PNG and other file types fine.

When I look at the plug-ins folder in `Edit > Preferences`, these two folder are listed:

```
I:\apps\GIMPPortable-2.8.22\Data\.gimp\plug-ins
I:\apps\GIMPPortable-2.8.22\App\gimp\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins
```

The first folder does not exist.  The `file-jpeg.exe` file can be found in the 2nd folder (the installer put it there), along with all the other standard plugin files.

On a whim, I created the first folder and copied `file-jpeg.exe` there...and GIMP then worked w/JPEG images as expected!  Thinking to make file management easier, I then moved ALL the plugins to that folder..but then GIMP would fail again, as before.

I have noticed that the "file-jpeg" is NOT listed in the pluginrc file upon initial install.  The pluginrc file is located here:

`I:\apps\GIMPPortable-2.8.22\Data\.gimp\pluginrc`

Once I copied `file-jpeg.exe` to the 2nd folder and re-started GIMP, that entry was then found in the pluginrc file.

I have attempted to create and use the file `GIMPPortable.ini`, containing a modified `PATH` statement (a supposed fix to this issue), but that did not work.

So copying `file-jpeg.exe` to the first plug-ins folder has got it working...but it is very hacky, and I'm sure I'm missing out on other plugins TBD later.  So my specific questions are:

**Why is this specific problem happening?**

**In general, is there a way to view error messages in GIMP?**

Thanks.

Comment: Gimp has an [error console](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-errors-dialog.html). This info is probably output to a log file somewhere, as well. You'll probably need to look at those errors in detail to answer your other question

Comment: @jpaugh, thanks for mentioning error console and providing the link.  I checked it out.  Unfortunately, it provided no more information than the graphical error dialog box that pops up.  I tried having it write the errors to file, but that contained no additional output either.  That made me think to look for a "verbosity" flag, though...details in solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on **jpaugh**'s suggestion to use the error console, I found the `--verbose` command line parameter.  This, coupled with `--console-messages` (both referenced [here](https://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Users:Tips#Getting_and_posting_the_output_of_gimp_--verbose)), I was able to get a better look at what was going on at GIMP start-up.

Googling the errors I found in the error console led me to [this thread](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-python-fu-script-no-more-working-after-gmic-installation), which recommended putting my G'MIC plugin files/folders in its own folder, and adding that folder to the list of plug-in folders under `Edit > Preferences`.

I am *still* not sure exactly what is going on (the verbose console doesn't mention anything specific that I can see), but clearly there is a conflict with the G'MIC plug-in files and `file-jpeg.exe`...but I'll stop here, as this is a reasonable solution.

I can now use *GIMPPortable* with JPEG support, and use the G'MIC plugin.  Hurray!